# R: step function not writing out complete model in result report

Tags: r, linear-regression

I am running the "step" function in RStudio on this model:

```
inputData.entry = lmer(height ~  ENTRY_NO + REP + (1|SUB.BLOCK), data=inputData); # our model
```

this is what I am running with "step" :

```
help.search("step",package="lmerTest");
st <- step(inputData.entry,  reduce.fixed=FALSE);
print(st);
```

Here is the output:

```
Backward reduced random-effect table:

                Eliminated npar  logLik    AIC     LRT Df Pr(>Chisq)
<none>                      142 -397.15 1078.3                      
(1 | SUB.BLOCK)          1  141 -397.47 1076.9 0.63157  1     0.4268

Backward reduced fixed-effect table:
         Eliminated  Df Sum of Sq    RSS    AIC F value    Pr(>F)    
ENTRY_NO          0 138    4238.1 6210.4 844.18  1.9775 5.749e-05 ***
REP               0   1      30.6 2002.9 816.03  1.9720    0.1627    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Model found:
height ~ ENTRY_NO + REP
```

My issue is the statement---- Model Found:

Why won't the results list "Sub.Block" in the model when inputData.entry shows it in "lmer"?

Is there something I am doing wrong?

Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step function selects a model according to [AIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akaike_information_criterion). Model found tells which model is selected according to these criteria. In this instance the algorithm tells us that Sub.Block doesn't bring meaningful information to the analysis over the added complicatoin it causes and thus it's not in the model suggested.